# "All you need is a good pair of glasses": What is the subject, and why?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subjects, verb-agreement, subject-or-object

What is the subject in the following sentence? And why?

> All you need is a good pair of glasses.

is the subject *All you need* OR *a good pair of glasses*?

If it's 'ALL', then, in a different context, we can be saying 'All you need are two pens'. Shall it be right?

Comment: The subject is `you`. The object is `a good pair of glasses`

Comment: [The subject of a sentence **is the person**, place, thing, or idea that is **doing** or **being something**.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/subjects.htm)

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction No, it isn't.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, it ain't :)

Answer (score -1):

The subject is the term to the left of the copula; the term to its right is the *subject complement*.

Thus “All you need” is the subject of the sentence; what you need — a good pair of glasses — is the subject complement.

When there is a difference in number between subject and predicate, the verb agrees with the term to the left of the copula. This is usually the subject:

> All you need is two pens.

In an inverse copular construction, the verb still matches the term to the left:

> Two pens are all you need.

In fact it may be moot whether the inverse copular construction actually occurs in English since there is no difference between the two: we could call “Two pens” the subject and the verb would agree with it. This differs from some other languages like German and Italian, which do have such a construction and where the verb continues to agree with the subject.

Answer (score -2):

The subject is *you*.

We can simplify this sentence for easier understanding like so:

> You need a good pair of glasses.

In this sentence, the verb is *need*. Hopefully this is already apparent. Next, to identify the subject you need to ask, "Who/what is needing something?" The answer is *you*. *You* need glasses. Now for the object, "What is needed?" The answer is *a good pair of glasses*.

> You(S) need(V) a good pair of glasses(O).

The function of *all* in this sentence is almost entirely insignificant. It is not the subject, verb, or object. Merriam-Webster's [*all* entry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all) says this:

> **all** (*adj.*)
>   6 : nothing but : ONLY

Using this, the sentence can be rewritten: *You need nothing but a good pair of glasses*.

Comment: When identifying grammatical components, rephrasing the original sentence is not the best idea. After all, grammar books often illustrate opposite concepts using sentences that mean the same thing.

Comment: @Area I've seen that. My rephrasing doesn't affect anything in this case.

Comment: Just saying. Btw, I wasn't the one who downvoted.

Comment: @Area I appreciate the concern. I do actually agree with you.

Comment: Actually your rephrasing does alter things because you have removed the copula and thus radically changed the grammatical construction. You may not have changed the meaning (although that is debatable), but the question does not concern the meaning.

Comment: @Andrew That's true, but my point in rephrasing is to identify the subject, verb, and object of a simpler sentence. I guess I'm only implying, and not explicitly stating, that my rephrasing and the original sentence share the same S, V, and O which is the downfall here.

Comment: But you can't alter the grammatical construction and **then** identify S, V, O. In general, the copular construction trumps everything else (rather like brackets in arithmetic) and removing it can radically change the result you get. Your "simpler sentence" is not the same sentence: more correct simpler sentences are *All is lost* or *Your need is glasses,* because they retain the copula.

Comment: @Andrew I surrender. You win this battle. +1 for you, sir.